# not able to connect to ActiveMQ outside network

Tags: android, tcp, activemq-classic

I have install `Apache ActiveMQ` on my `VPS ( virtual private server)` , now the issue is when i am trying to make a connection in android using following TCP urls

"tcp://134.12.333.44@61616" // not able to connect

"tcp://134.12.333.44@1883" // not able to connect

but i am not able to connect it and getting following exception in android

```
 MqttException: MQIsdp ClientId > 23 bytes
```

here is the content of my activemq.xml

```
 <transportConnectors>
            <!-- DOS protection, limit concurrent connections to 1000 and frame size to 100MB -->
            <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="amqp" uri="amqp://0.0.0.0:5672?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="stomp" uri="stomp://0.0.0.0:61613?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="mqtt" uri="mqtt://0.0.0.0:1883?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="ws" uri="ws://0.0.0.0:61614?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
        </transportConnectors>
```

as i am accessing ActiveMQ outside network , i have change above configuration by my server it
i.e **134.12.333.44** (its a fake ip just to show an example)

```
    <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://134.12.333.44:61616?

maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>



     <transportConnector name="mqtt" uri="mqtt://134.12.333.44:1883?

maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your android client is MQTT then trying to connect to port 61616 is definitely not going to work as that's your configured OpenWire transport connector, so don't do that.  As for the connection to 1883 you probably need to have the port opened on your firewall since I don't see any reference to that step in your question.

Just because you configured those ports on ActiveMQ doesn't make them accessible to the outside world.  You need to configure or have your network admin configure your firewall to allow traffic in on that port also.